# C#: Using var to point to 2 different objects

Tags: c#

In C#, i would like to do something like this:

```
    var apiClient = attachments.Any() ? 
_amsWsapiClientFactory.Create(ctx.AmsLoginEmployeeCode) : 
_amsApiClientFactory.Create<IActivitiesApi>(ctx.AmsApiLoginEmail);
```

But the problem here is that `_amsWsapiClientFactory.Create(ctx.AmsLoginEmployeeCode)` returns an object of type: `IAmsWSAPIClient` and the second one (`_amsApiClientFactory.Create<IActivitiesApi>(ctx.AmsApiLoginEmail)`) returns object of type `IActivitiesApi` and there is bound to be conversion problems.

Is there a better way to write the above condition where I can use one variable to point to either of the api clients depending on the condition (`attachments.Any()`)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? In short you could use a more base type or contract as the type of the variable, or you could use `object`

Comment: you can always do `object apiClient = ...` (provided both methods return an object, not a `struct`) but that means that you won't be able to access methods and properties without casting and/or reflection

Comment: There is no covariance in C#... so short answer is NO.... On the other hand if both objects implement the same interface or inherit from the same base class you could cast the result so that they both become the same type.  "var" in C# is NOT like var in "javascript".  In C# will be converted to an actual type a compile time so it is NOT a dynamic type.  Basically C# will "infer" the type and change "var" for "int" for example.. or what ever the type might be

Comment: In simple words, No it is `not possible` to assign two `different types` to `same variable`. But if you want to perform same action from both then you can `implement` one `interface` (for ex IApiClient) to both and set type as `interface` `IApiClient apiClient`.

Comment: C# is statically-typed. The compiler must be able to determine the **SINGLE** type that each variable is declared as.